# jQuery select sibling onclick

Tags: jquery

I would like to get the contents of the first TD when I click the 3rd TD
I can get the contents of the TD right next to the clicked on but not the one 2 TDs over
what am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div id="Message">Should Be replaced with Just the #1 from first TD</div>
<table border='1'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>xxxx</td>
            <td class="Click">Click Me</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$('.Click').click(function () {
    alert('Fired');
    $('#Message').html($(this).prev().prev().html);
    alert('Done');
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kdew5z6w/)

Comment: It's `.html()`, not `.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `.html` as a property and not `.html()` as a method, which is what I assume you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/kdew5z6w/1/

Answer (score 0):

You call as `html()` not as `html`

use `$('#Message').html($(this).prev().prev().html());`

```js
$('.Click').click(function() {
  alert('Fired');
  $('#Message').html($(this).prev().prev().html());
  alert('Done');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Message">Should Be replaced with Just the #1 from first TD</div>
<table border='1'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>xxxx</td>
      <td class="Click">Click Me</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked, you can try this:

```
$('.Click').click(function () {
    alert('Fired');
    $('#Message').html($(this).siblings(':first').text());
    alert('Done');
});
```